# How do you remove fonts from the Favorite collection in the Fonts dialog?

Tags: font

As titled. For example, if you bring up the Fonts dialog in Mail.app (<kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>), and add a wrong font by accident to the Favorite collection (gear icon → Add to Favorites), how can you remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grab it in the list & drag it out to the desktop - like you would with an app in the dock, etc.

You should see the little puff of smoke & it's gone.

[image]